# sending an http request in unit tests?

Tags: offchain, unit-tests, https

I'm trying to arrange some unit tests for a local http server connectivity my node communicates with.

While the `node` has no troubles while sending requests, I face difficulties trying to build basic unit tests for this functionality.

My code looks as follows:

```rust
    let (mut offchain, _offchain_state) = TestOffchainExt::with_offchain_db(ext.offchain_db());
    ext.register_extension(OffchainWorkerExt::new(offchain.clone()));
    if let Ok(request) = offchain.http_request_start("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:9800", &[]) {
        offchain.http_response_wait(&[request], None);
    }
```

which yields a panic in
`primitives/core/src/offchain/testing.rs -> fn http_response_wait(...)`

I also tried to run a similar logic inside the externalities context like so:

```rust
    ext.register_extension(OffchainWorkerExt::new(offchain.clone()));
    ext.execute_with(|| {
        Request::get("http://127.0.0.1:9800").send().map(PendingRequest::wait);
    // snip
```

with exactly the same result.

And I can see that on the server side no request arrives.
On the other hand when I run the node everything works fine, so I guess this is not a server problem and I must have missed something.

Comment: I looked at it a little bit more and it seems that the ```PendingRequest``` in ```/primitives/core/src/offchain/testing.rs``` is created and inserted into the offchain state directly without the Request being sent in the function  ```fn http_request_start```. At least I was unable to found a code equivalent to ```Request::sent(...)``` which normally creates a ```PendingRequest``` instance.

Comment: I adopted ```should_send_a_basic_request_and_get_response``` test from ```/primitives/runtime/src/offchain/http.rs``` which manipulates the state and fullfills the request, unfortunately, it seems to pass always, no matter what the port number is and even if the local server is down.

Comment: This test might help you: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/client/executor/runtime-test/src/lib.rs#L220

Comment: @Alex Bean thank you for prompt reply. I adopted the suggested test for running under externalities, still it yields exactly the same result: the request is not sent and the ```/primitives/core/src/offchain/testing.rs/http_request_start``` calls for a panic!. Even if it would succeed, still my underlying problem is that my pallet uses offchain worker that implements a protocol based on http and, at this point, it looks like I would need to modify the working code in order to just adapt it for testing. I'm more inclined to try to modify relevant code in Substrate itself, could you give hints?